# how to upload php website into remote server

Tags: php, mysql, server, web-hosting

I am new to deploying websites to a remote server. I have been searching for the steps that I should follow to do that for a long time but have not found any results.

here is what I have done 'til now:

1- I used a free web hosting called 0fees.us.

2- Got sub-domain name from the web host.

3- Upload my files as .zip in htdocs directory using the online file manger in cPanel.

4- Upload my database using mysql in cPanel.

5- Change the database configuration in the my website.

After that I typed the sub-domain in the URL field but it get a browser error says:

> the connection to the server was reset while the page was loading

What else should I do, so I can type the domain name I see my website on the browser?

Comment: did you upload the index page to the server?

Comment: what is the index page? there is a an html page in the htdocs named index2.html but not me who upload it it was there from the start

Comment: What all did you upload in the site?

Comment: i uploaded all the php pages along with other folders i created form css and js, also there was a project file and buildpath page

Comment: give the url to the website and also 2 or 3 names of the files that you uploaded

Comment: Website name: http://imamuc.0fees.us

Comment: pages: login.php, AdminHome.php

Comment: http://imamuc.0fees.us/login.php, clicking this url does not open login.php that means that you did not upload the files correctly to you public folder

Comment: You did unzip that file after uploading, yes? Why not use FTP instead.

Comment: i changed the name of login page to index.php and the website run i have another problem that when i enter the username and password it says that they are wrong. which mean that query couldn't fetch the username and password from the DB. can you please tell me wat should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change/configure nameserver settings that points domain to your server ip address.Delete the default index page. And rename the main page you want to display initially to index.html or index.php

Comment: excuse me, but can you tell me where i should configure nameserver?

Comment: login to your domain registrator website.There might be domain settings.Also change it in your cpanel of free server.Find your server ip address in your cpanel and type in your browser to check.

Comment: thanks it works with me but i have another problem the website did connect to the database even that i have changed the database configration

Comment: You want to connect database or disconnect?You are not saying it clearly.How do you changed database configuration?You have to be more specific.Have you created database?Are u using CMS?

Comment: i am sorry, i made a login page that connect to database to check if the user recorded in the database or not. i have php file that contain all the information for database connection (host_name, username, password, db_name) this database was imported from my pc. so when upload it to the server using MySql i changed the (host_name, username, password, db_name) to the names that Cpanel provided me with them.

Comment: Just check your online server database name, username and password.You can change the default database name, username and password.If it is not already set username and password.It might contain servername on your database username like this "acd123123_user". database name = "acd123123_database".It's common in free web servers.Once you've set the database settings on server,edit and replace it in your php script.Btw it's better if you create database manually.